# Concepts: API Level Testing

Tags: testing, api

I'm college grad, soon to be graduating. SO i have started my job search. So my question is for New Grad who is interested in QA (API Level testing in particular). What is level of knowledge in **JAVA** required? I'm not that great in Java but can rate myself 5/10.

So do companies expect candidate to have extensive coding knowledge in java or just basic java

Again if its just basic java, what concepts should i focus more on ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your question, I assume that you're looking at a Java API testing gig (otherwise, java experience wouldn't make much of a difference).

Do you have experience in another language? As far as API testing goes, the basics of testing in one language apply to another.

What you want to be able to do is:

- Look at the individual input values and identify potential problem values
- Understand how input parameters can interact - or where they do not interact
- Build a good oracle - i.e. know whether the API succeeded or not by knowing what behavior should happen *beyond* the return value
- Keep usability in mind - since it's a public interface, can developers use the API to create a useful application?

Lot's more, but I'm slightly off topic on the answer. Again, the short answer is that if you are a 7-8+ on *any* language, I think you'll be fine as a java api tester.

Comment: Okay, let me put it in proper way, I have an onsite interview coming up shortly, so i'm going to be interviewed by a QA team which is into API testing, am good at cracking algorithm, but when it comes to actual coding , my heart starts beating faster :( So any suggestions on which topics i need to cover for API testing ?

Comment: As far as coding skill goes, you're probably going to have to perform, so spend some time practicing. Pick some common Java APIs and practice testing them. The bigger part of testing is probably in the bullet points, but depending on the org, you will probably have to prove you can code the answer.